# Вывод в DataGridView двух связанных таблиц програмным способом

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net

Приложение с базой данных Access. У меня есть 2 DataGridView. Необходимо, чтобы при выборе значения в первом DataGridView во втором DataGridView выводились только значения, связанные с этой строчкой.
 То есть при выборе в первом DataGridView фамилии во вотором все его телефоны. Таблицы связаны один ко многим. Хочу реализовать это программным способом.
[image: Связь таблиц как на рисунке]

Answer (score 1):

Пример на Master-Details "Книжные полки"-"Книги" отношение `один-ко-многим`.

[image: пример]

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private const string _conString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                                      "Initial Catalog=DatabaseOneToMany;" +
                                      "Integrated Security=True;";
    //запрос на выборку сразу двух таблиц
    private const string _selectString = "SELECT * FROM Library.Shelves;SELECT * FROM Library.Books";
    private readonly DataSet _dataSet;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataSet = new DataSet();
        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectString, _conString))
        {
            //загружаем данные сразу из двух таблиц
            var readed = adp.Fill(_dataSet);
            Trace.WriteLine($"Загружено {readed}");
        }

        //даем названия таблицам
        _dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "shelves";
        _dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "books";

        //назначаем первичные ключи
        _dataSet.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("PK_Shelves", _dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0], true);
        _dataSet.Tables[1].Constraints.Add("PK_Books", _dataSet.Tables[1].Columns[0], true);

        //создаем связь между таблицами по внешнему ключу
        _dataSet.Relations.Add("FK_Books_Shelves", _dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0],
            _dataSet.Tables[1].Columns["ShelfId"]);

        //отображаем данные родительской (Master) таблицы
        _dataGridViewMaster.DataSource = _dataSet.Tables["shelves"];
        //отображаем данные дочерней таблицы (Details)
        LoadChildData(0);

        //подписываемся на событие выделения строки в родительской DGV
        _dataGridViewMaster.SelectionChanged += DataGridViewMaster_SelectionChanged;
    }

    //отображение записей из дочерней таблицы
    private void LoadChildData(int rowIndex)
    {
        //определяем по индексу выделенную строку в родительской таблице
        var parentRow = _dataSet.Tables["shelves"].Rows[rowIndex];
        //получаем коллекцию строк из дочерней таблицы с помощью связи
        var childRows = parentRow.GetChildRows("FK_Books_Shelves");
        //создаем временную таблицу для записей из дочерней таблицы
        var childTable = _dataSet.Tables["books"].Clone();
        //заполняем эту временную таблицу
        foreach (var row in childRows)
        {
            childTable.ImportRow(row);
        }
        //отображем дочерние записи
        _dataGridViewDetails.DataSource = childTable;
    }

    //когда происходит выбор строки в родительской DGV
    //подгружаем данные для дочернего DGV
    private void DataGridViewMaster_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //определяем индекс выбранной строки и подгружаем данные
        LoadChildData(_dataGridViewMaster.CurrentRow.Index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо. Будем пробовать! =)

Comment: Ну, пробуйте...